# Phase ship that travels by computation of coordinates

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the author and title of a story about a phase ship that departs the Earth against orders. They visit a few planets meeting alien races and empty planets and then return home to possible court martial.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about this you can [edit] in? Any plot details? What media it was? When you read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Mission to Universe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2271860.Mission_to_Universe) by Gordon R. Dickson.

[This review](https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/review/blinded-by-nostalgia) mentions the "phase ship" and a hijacking.

> Four! Billion! People! share an overcrowded Earth. More than fifty nations have armed themselves with nuclear weapons of stupendous power. Nobody wants a nuclear war, but nobody can see a way to safely disarm. All they can do is watch each other nervously while waiting for some crisis to trigger the final war.
>
> Benjamin Shore thinks America’s newly developed phase ship, able to bridge interstellar distances in an instant, could be humanity’s salvation. Habitable worlds around other stars could provide a much needed release valve for Earth’s population. Shore’s superiors disagree; they worry that the phase ship could itself be the spark needed to set off World War Three.
>
> Following the delivery of covert orders from Washington, Shore hastily assembles a crew and takes the Phase Ship Mark III into deepest space. Once there, he reveals a heavily redacted copy of their orders: to boldly go search the sky until the Phase Ship Mark III finds a new home for humanity!
>
> What Shore’s crew cannot know is that Shore’s redactions conceal the truth; the President never ordered the ship into space. The mission is a fraud.

Comment: 4 billion... overcrowded... wonder how he'd describe the current population?

Comment: @HorusKol - *Very* overcrowded.

Comment: Thank you! That was a fun story. Now I can revisit.

Comment: @KennethJustice - [Happy to help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)